# Error uploading file to Amazon S3

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want t upload a csv file from my iOS App (written in Swift) to my amazon S3 bucket. To do this I'm using following code:

```
//Create
let fileName = "Export.csv"
let path = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(fileName)
csvText = CreateCSVAccount()
do {
   try csvText.write(to: path!, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf32BigEndian)
   //Prepare Upload
   let uploadingFileURL = path
   let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()
   let Bucketname = "mybucket/CSV"
   uploadRequest?.bucket = Bucketname
   uploadRequest?.key = "mycsvfile.csv"
   uploadRequest?.body = uploadingFileURL!

   //Upload File
    transferManager.upload(uploadRequest!).continueWith(executor: AWSExecutor.mainThread(), block: { (task:AWSTask<AnyObject>) -> Any? in
        if let error = task.error as NSError? {
            if error.domain == AWSS3TransferManagerErrorDomain, let code = AWSS3TransferManagerErrorType(rawValue: error.code) {
                switch code {
                case .cancelled, .paused:
                    break
                default:
                    print("Error Contact uploading: \(String(describing: uploadRequest?.key)) Error: \(error)")
                }
            } else {
                print("Error Contact uploading: \(String(describing: uploadRequest?.key)) Error: \(error)")
            }
            return nil
        }
        let uploadOutput = task.result
        print("Upload complete for: \(String(describing: uploadRequest?.key))")
        print("uploadOutput: \(String(describing: uploadOutput))")
        return nil
    })
} catch {
    print("Failed to create file")
    print("\(error)")
}
```

The problem is sometimes it works and sometimes I'm receiving the following error:

```
Message=You did not provide the number of bytes specified by the Content-Length HTTP header, NumberBytesExpected=412, Code=IncompleteBody, RequestId=075D1F5B0A377E89
```

Can somebody please help me?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add the `contentLength` header to your request.

That is:

```swift
uploadRequest?.contentLength = 1234
```

where 1234 is an NSNumber representing the number of bytes in body